# Массивы и подсчет

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть хлебные крошки, в массиве `@tracks` , я их перебираю

```
<% @tracks.map do |track| %>
```

и внутри этого кода формируются списки (выпадающее меню из хлебных крошек) в зависимости от условий некоторых.

```
<% if track[:url] %>
    <%= link_to( track[:name], track[:url]) %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to( track[:name], slug_path(track[:slug])) %>
<% end %>
<ul>
    <%- childrens.each do |child| -%>
     <li>
       <%= link_to(child['name'], child['slug']) %>
     </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Мне нужно поставить ограничения,на `@tracks.count-2`  Чтобы не выводилась лишняя `ul`, пустаяю

Comment: Может проще \@tracks преобразовать в коллекцию, которая не будет приводить к вывода лишнего пустого списка? Например при помощи \@tracks.select { ... }.each. Правда, чтобы помочь в этом направлении, вам потребуется рассказать больше про структуру \@tracks и что происходит в childerns

Comment: А зачем там `map`? Почему не `each`? Вы же возвращаемое значение выкидываете.

Comment: Извините, забыл добавить то,что я делаю,союственно, я его не выкидываю, делаю ссылку. Я только начал изучать Ruby, поэтому с некоторыми свойствами и методами не знаком.

Comment: Нет, *возвращаемое значение* `map` вы именно что выкидываете (ибо вызов в `<% %>`, а не `<%= %>`); а ссылку вы *выводите* (как побочный эффект в computer science; как `puts` возвращает `nil`, но что-то печатает на экран). По идее, `each` там хватит.

Comment: (`<% %>` и нет явного присваивания куда бы там ни было ещё)

Comment: Проблема только в том, что для пустого `children` выводится пустой список? Так заверните его в `if`, проверяющий, не пуст ли список (`unless childrens.empty?` например). PS: children это уже множественное число, единственное для него child.

Comment: Да, это я знаю, children уже было занято, мне лучшего в голову не пришло) Да все работает через if и проверка на empty.Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

на выбор

1. `@tracks[0..-2]`
2. `@tracks.take(@tracks.count - 2)`